# What is the motivation of using a Vector based implementation of a Stack in Java instead of a linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

What was the motivation of using a `Vector` based implementation of a `Stack` in Java instead over a linked list implementation?  I realize a `Vector` is synchronized and that has inherit advantages (and overhead), but I feel like not only are these data structures typically taught in texts as linked list based structures but LLs avoid costly resizes as the underlying array fills.

I do understand that `Vectors`, using amortized analysis, are O(1) even with the resizes.  So maybe taking this into consideration it doesn't make much of a difference, but I would be curious to understand the rationale none the less.

Comment: How does this compare to ArrayLists?

Comment: Before anyone else complains, Stack and Vector are considered to be on the way to deprecation. You should consider using an `ArrayList` instead, and, if synchronization is needed, synchronize the ArrayList with `Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList)`.

Comment: Why are Vectors on the way out? You can store multiple variables in one object and store the object as an entry in a vector.

Comment: @Matt As you can with ArrayLists and that without all the cruft and being able to use it with the collections API..

Comment: `Vector`'s crude synchronization technique is almost never actually what you need, even if you do want some kind of synchronization.  That's why `Vector` is "on the way out."  For this specific question, `ArrayDeque` is probably the modern replacement for `Stack`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linked-lists have the following disadvantages:

- Per-element storage overhead
- Computational complexity from having to follow pointers/references from element to element
- Bad cache locality

Of course, these are just generic disadvantages of linked-lists; I have no idea whether they affected the decision for what to base `Queue` and `Stack` on.

Comment: The second point does not affect stacks in any way, as you only need to work at one end, so you make that end the head. For queues, a doubly-linked list with a pointer to the last node may work, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4):

A vector stores its data in contiguous memory. This is good for caching.

A linked list can become very fragmented in memory.